# In Julia, a value accessed from a matrix failed to be used as an argument in a function

Tags: julia

First, I have a function called permeability.

```
# permeabiliy function
# L is short for the Lable  
mu_0 = 4 * pi * 10^(-7);
mu_r_core = 50;
mu_r_air = 1;
L = Int16; 
function permeability(L)
    if L in 1:4
        if L !== 3 
            return mu = mu_r_air * mu_0
        else
            return mu = mu_r_core * mu_0
        end
    else
        println("null") #print output in a new line
    end
end
```

Then, I have a matrix called **domain**, which is shown below,

```
 domain
 2392-element Array{Int16,1}:
 1
 1
 3
 1
...
```

When I called permeability(domain[3]), the output is,

```
L = domain[3]
permeability(L)
```

the output is

```
1.2566370614359177e-6
```

However, when I simply called permeability(3),

```
permeability(3)
```

the output is

```
6.283185307179588e-5
```

So, it seems that the value passed from matrix **domain** is just "1", but in this case, domain[3] should be 3 and the result should be the same in these 2 cases.

Can someone please tell me where I was wrong?

Comment: Oscar's is correct, but there are a few other things that are wrong with your code. Most important is probably to avoid exponentiating integers (i.e., do `1e-7` instead of `10^(-7)`) and to make your function type stable. (Use `@code_warntype permeability(3)` to check the types inferred.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your amazing remarks! I am gonna check them out. Hope to talk you soon once I have new findings : )

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that your array stores `Int16` while `3` is an `Int64`. `L!==3` requires `L` to be of the same type as `3` ie `Int64`. You wanted instead `L!=3`. Your confusion probably comes from the fact that `!=` is the inverse of `==` while `!==` is the inverse of `===`

Comment: Truly thanks, Oscar! It does work for me! I will pay more attention to "!==" and "!=" next time : )